# Bat file to find and kill torrent clients such as Utorrent / Vuze

Tags: batch-file

I am looking for a way to create a bat file to kill torrent clients. I wanna used it as my openvpn client gui up script.
I do some research and I got this.

```
@echo off 
set loopcount=5
:loop
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions
set EXE=uTorrent.exe
set EXE=vuze.exe
FOR /F %%x IN ('tasklist /NH /FI "IMAGENAME eq %EXE%"') DO IF %%x == %EXE% 
goto FOUND
goto FIN
:FOUND
taskkill /f /t /im openvpn.exe
exit
:FIN
timeout /t 100
set /a loopcount=loopcount-1
if %loopcount%==0 goto exitloop
goto loop
:exitloop
pause
```

At first I think I does work, but when I retry it again, It won't work anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

may be,

```
@echo off 
SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion & set "pid="

for /L %%c in (1,1,5) do (
  for %%a in (uTorrent.exe vuze.exe) do (
    for /F "tokens=2" %%x in ('tasklist /NH /FI "IMAGENAME eq %%a"') do set/A pid=%%x
    if !pid! NEQ 0 goto:FOUND
  )
  timeout /t 100 & rem >NUL
)
pause
exit/B

:FOUND
taskkill /f /t /im openvpn.exe
exit
```

Comment: So to use it with openvpn I created the the file myovpn_up.bat and on it I put `start /b up.vbs` and on my up.vbs I put this to hide the bat you gave me `Dim WshShell
Dim obj
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
obj = WshShell.Run("killtorrent.bat", 0) 
set WshShell = Nothing` when openvpn connects it opens a cmd of the myovpn.bat to execute the up.vbs. How I will able to hide the cmd window of the myovpn.bat? And How to make it finally stop after 1 hr, your bat? Because it might eat cpu if continues countdown if no torrent app found right? Thanks man. @elzooilogico